# Is it possible to generate function dynamically in rebol or red

Tags: code-generation, rebol, red

Instead of hard coding (contrived example here):

```
    f1: func[][print "f1"]
    f100: func[][print "f100"]
    etc...
```

Is it possible to do something like this

```
    for num 1 100 1 [ 
      set to-word rejoin ["f" num] func[][
        print rejoin ["f" num]
      ]
    ]
```

except it doesn't work, it always give "f100" (why in fact num is equal to 100 is a mystery for me though it's not the question here: closure ?).

Comment: See also the related Rosetta Code entry: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Closures/Value_capture#Red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for num 1 100 1 [ 
  set to-word rejoin ["f" num] func[] compose/deep [
    print rejoin  ["f"  (num)]
  ]
]

>> f1
f1
>> f2
f2
>> f99
f99
```

The result of your functions is always f100, because they all share the same word **num** with the outcome of your for loop. You can see that if you do e.g.`source f1`.